# Print 20 prime numbers in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I'm able to generate 1000 prime numbers but i'm unable to print the numbers on new rows

```
lower = 1
upper = 1000
print("The prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are:")
for num in range(lower + 1, upper + 1):
  if (num % 2) != 0 and (num % 3) != 0:
    print(num,end='')
  elif num//2 == 1:
    print(num,end='')
```

My project is to print prime numbers between 0 and 1000, but also to partition a list of 1000 prime numbers into 20 numbers per row

Comment: You should start by properly identing your code in your question

Comment: Your current code is full of indentation errors. You should probably also think about how to reduce this to a [mre]. Is your real question "how can I partition a list into chunks of 20?"

Comment: Use `\n`, `print(num,end='\n')`

Comment: Not all of your "prime" numbers are actually prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not all your *prime numbers* are actually** [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers#The_first_1000_prime_numbers).
You need to append a line break (`\n`) after the desired number to print it on a new line.
I'd also separate `primes` and `composites`, something like:

```
lower, upper = 1, 1000
primes, composites = [], []

for number in range(lower + 1, upper + 1):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if (number % i) == 0:
            composites.append(number)
            break
    else:
        primes.append(number)

print("primes")
for prime in primes:
    print(prime,end='\n')

print("composites")
for composite in composites:
    print(composite,end='\n')

print("List of prime numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers")
```

---

- [Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/3e2660f385)
- [Check If a number is Prime or not](https://beginnersbook.com/2018/01/python-program-check-prime-or-not/)

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
print(num,end='')
```

use:

```
print(num,end='\n')
```

or just:

```
print(num) # Default end is '\n'
```

NOTE:

> **print()**
>
> Definition and Usage The print() function prints the specified message
>   to the screen, or other standard output device.
>
> The message can be a string, or any other object, the object will be
>   converted into a string before written to the screen.
>
> *Syntax:*
>
> ```
> print(object(s), separator=separator, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
> ```
>
> *Parameter Values:*
>
> *object(s)* : Any object, and as many as you like. Will be converted to string before printed
>
> *sep* : 'separator'   (Optional) Specify how to separate the objects, if there is more than one. Default is `' '`
>
> *end* : 'end' (Optional) Specify what to print at the end. Default is `'\n'` (line feed)
>
> *file* : (Optional) An object with a write method. Default is `sys.stdout`
>
> *flush* : (Optional) A Boolean, specifying if the output is flushed (True) or buffered (False). Default is `False`

Answer (score 0):

if by new rows you mean a jump line your issue is in 
print(num,end='')

the end = '' means what you want to add after the num variable, to fix that add end = '\n'

The print will jump a line after each print num